# Commands work in terminal, but not as a script

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I have a .command script that uses HTK to get PLP coefficients from a .wav file. Each individual command works in the terminal, but I cannot get the .command script to work. It does not give me an error, it just doesn't run the commands. I have looked at countless other stack overflow/super user posts about this, but cannot seem to figure it out. Here is a short sample of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Users/lisa/Documents/NSP/Output/Sentence3
mkdir at0H0_3_11025
HCopy -C config.plp -s 274376.417234 -e 1571428.57143 at0H0_3_11025.wav ./at0H0_3_11025/at0H0_3_11025_T_0.0274376417234.htk
HList ./at0H0_3_11025/at0H0_3_11025_T_0.0274376417234.htk > ./at0H0_3_11025/at0H0_3_11025_T_0.0274376417234.txt
```

I believe my shebang line is right, as `which bash` returns `/bin/bash`. I have tried various things such as running it from the `Sentence3` directory and eliminating the `cd` line, running it from where the `.command` file is located, etc. I am new to writing a script like this, so the problem may be something obvious and small. Thank you.

Comment: Try changing your shebang for `/bin/bash -eux` - it'll probably help you identify where the problem is. [info](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)

Comment: Could you also share the filename, and it's permissions? (e.g: `stat -c '%A' ${FILENAME}`)

Comment: `stat -c '%A' ${runHTK.command}` returns `-bash: ${runHTK.command}: bad substitution`. Also, I tried adding `-eux` to my shebang line and nothing changes

Comment: Ok... I've figured it out. I used `chmod 755 runHTK.command` and then double clicked on it from my desktop. Why it worked? I have no idea, as I had been running it with `chmod u+x runHTK.command`

Comment: Great! Scripts are typically given the `*.sh` extension. Also if you run it from a terminal / shell (instead of clicking) you'll probably see issues like that much more readily.

Comment: re: `stat`... I had expected you to run `stat -c '%A' runHTK.command`, which would show the human readable permissions bits.

Comment: Oops! Thank you for letting me know where I went wrong! There's lots to learn.